# Jquery function to return url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jquery function I can call to retrieve url paramaters.

I have been using this function below and it works fine but it breaks when the url has no parameters. I want it to return '' when there

```
    function getUrlParameter(name)
     {
   var results = new RegExp('[\\?&amp;]' + name + '=([^&amp;#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
 return results[1] || 0;

      }
```

So for  www.mywebsite.com/index?var1=foo calling getUrlParameter(var1) should return foo and for www.mywebsite.com getUrlParameter(var1) should return ' '

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score -1):

To implement this, I have created a function which returns value of any parameters variable.

> function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
>       var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
>       var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
>       for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
>       {
>           var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
>           if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
>           {
>               return sParameterName[1];
>           }
>       } }​

And this is how you can use this function assuming the URL is,
 "http://dummy.com/?technology=jquery&blog=jquerybyexample".

> var tech = GetURLParameter('technology'); var blog =
>   GetURLParameter('blog');

So in above code variable "tech" will have "jQuery" as value and "blog" variable's will be "jquerybyexample".

Comment: I want it to work for urls with no variable so if I call getUrlParameter('blog') would return '' for www.mywebsite.com